# PHP: write a remote file to a directory, without chmod 777

Tags: php, permissions, chmod

On my (shared) webhost, I'm using PHP's curl and fopen to download and save a remote XML-file to a specific directory. The system has to read and execute it later.
Right now, I've created the directory beforehand (permissions: 777) and the system is able to write the XML-file in the directory.

I am afraid that giving permissions to anyone to read, write and execute is a security risk. 
Therefore, my questions are:

1. Is setting chmod to 777 a security risk in this case?
2. Is there a way to achieve the desired results without setting chmod to 777?

*(Since I am a beginner, I'm not (yet) familiar with file users, file groups and file permissions. Is there a way that only "the system" is able to read, execute and write?)*

Comment: How did you create the directory in question? FTP, control panel, shell access? Have you tried if it works if you chmod it to `0755` instead of `0777`? Your PHP code is likely to be running as the same user as the owner of the directory (i.e. the user you created the directory as).

Comment: I've created the directory via FTP. Chmod 0755 returns a permission error, when accessing it via the PHP-page. The PHP is temporarily publicly accessible for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should avoid 777 alltogether.
2. There is a way. Such problems are better solved via chown than chmod. One way is to make sure the user that writes the files (normally apache or www) belongs to the group of the folder owner then set permissions to maxiamlly 775.

Comment: 2.; I thought so, but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: If you can't do it, it's time to change to a VPS!

Comment: I'm not sure if I am able to do it. VPS is not an option yet.

Comment: Why not? It's a minimum must for every PHP dev! It's impossible to do good work with a shared hosting.

Comment: As a beginner, I feel that I don't need a VPS yet. I am only working on personal projects to learn some more.

Comment: I forgot to accept this answer a year ago. My advice is to work with a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu (i.e. VMWare) when working on personal projects, so one can learn some linux basics as well.

Answer (score 0):

To allow only the owner to read, execute, and write, change the permissions to 0700.